# declare class data type in class?

Tags: c#

i want to understand what is doing this declaration :

```
public Node Next;
```

in this class :

```
internal class Node
        {
            public T Info;
            public Node Next;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`public Node Next;` in this instance is providing a reference to another object of type `Node`.

This sort of construct is called a linked-list where each node points to the next node in the chain.

Answer (score 1):

I think Node is nested type of some generic collection and used to store collection items.

Class Node implements linked list ([Linked_list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list)) where each node points to next node.

Each node:

- contain useful data (Info property of type T);
- point to next node (Next property of node type);

Answer (score 1):

Create a chain of Class, for Example:Create a Tree of Nodes